# Error al crear un nuevo proyecto en Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: java, android

Al momento de crear un nuevo proyecto en Android Studio 2.3.3 me sale el siguiente error:

> Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. You can configure your SDK via Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs

Consiguen ayudarme a resolver este problema?

Comment: Intenta [estos siete pasos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18242900/5587982), si funciona sería posible traducirlo y ponerlo como respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Selecciona tu proyecto y da click en la tecla "F4". ¿Que muestra en Android SDK  Location?

Comment: Aveces hay un problema de Android Studio... y es que cuando lo descargas no descarga el sdk, intenta instalando esto...: https://android-sdk.uptodown.com/windows

Answer (score 1):

El error que describes indica que android studio no encuentra la carpeta donde esta situado el SDK de android, o faltan algunos archivos de este. Entra en configuración y comprueba que la ruta a la carpeta es correcta, y si es correcta abre el SDK manager y comprueba que no tienes ningún paquete roto. Si el SDK lo tienes bien no tendría que darte mas fallos.